# The length of a poset

Tags: order-theory

Let $(X,\le)$ be a (nonempty) poset. The length of $(X,\le)$ is defined by
$$\operatorname{len}(X)=\sup\{|C|-1\mid C\subseteq X \text{ is a chain} \}$$

Can $\sup$ be replaced by $\max$? (without changing notion/definition of $\text{len}$)

Comment: If $X$ is meant to be finite, this should be added explicitly as an assumption. If not, you need to explain your notation.

Comment: $|C|-1$ is the same as $|C|$ if $C$ is not finite. The length is a cardinality (finite or infinite).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\sup$ can always be replaced by $\max$, if you're dealing with finite collections.  However $\sup \{1,2,3,\ldots\}=\infty$ is defined, while $\max\{1,2,3,\ldots\}$ isn't. j

Also $\sup\{-1,-\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{4},-\frac{1}{8},\ldots\}=0$ while $\max \{-1,-\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{4},-\frac{1}{8},\ldots\}$ is again undefined.  That's not really relevant to this problem, though, since your elements are isolated.

Comment: That's not really relevant because the supremum above is taken on a set of cardinalities and not real numbers. that's why I had added set-theory tag.

Comment: by the way, the first example is a good counter example. It seems it can extended to infinite cases (when there's at least an infinite chain).

Answer (score 2):

Using ordinals we can produce simple examples: Consider for instance the set $\bigcup_n\omega_n\times\{n\}$, where $(\alpha,n)<(\beta,m)$ iff $n=m$ and $\alpha<\beta$. Here, there are chains of any length below $\aleph_\omega$, but not of length $\aleph_\omega$. (This example also shows that the cofinality of a partially ordered set can be singular.)

In the same spirit but not requiring any use of ordinals, consider $\bigcup_n n\times\{n\}$, with the same ordering. Here we have chains of any finite length, but no infinite chains.

Or, for any infinite cardinal $\kappa$, consider $\bigcup_{\alpha<\kappa}\alpha\times\{\alpha\}$, again with the same ordering. We have chains of every ordinal length below $\kappa$, but none of length $\kappa$ itself. If $\kappa$ is a limit cardinal, this gives us another example as in the first paragraph: Chains of every cardinality below $\kappa$, so the supremum of their lengths is $\kappa$, and yet no chain of length $\kappa$ itself.

Comment: thanks. this is a simple counterexample for infinite case.